# How to generate and 7-digit random number/special character string in VB.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I generate a 7-digit random number and special character string in a textbox on a button click event, in VB.Net?

Comment: Can you elaborate more please. Give example of what you want to output to be. What special character did you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the characters you want in a string and pick from that:

```
Dim chars As String = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#%&()?+-;:"
Dim word As Char() = New Char(6)
Dim rnd As New Random()
For i As Integer = 0 To word.Length - 1
  word(i) = chars.Chars(rnd.Next(chars.Length))
Next
TheTextBox.Text = New String(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a light weight version i use:

```
Protected Function GetRandomPass() As String
    Dim pass As String = String.Empty
    Dim AllowedChars() As String = {"ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ", "abcdefghjklmnpqrstwxyz", "0123456789"}
    Dim rnd = New Random()
    While pass.Length < 10
        Dim rndSet As Integer = rnd.Next(0, AllowedChars.Length)
        pass &= AllowedChars(rndSet).Substring(rnd.Next(0, AllowedChars(rndSet).Length), 1)
    End While
    Return pass
End Function
```

it chooses a random index of the `AllowedChars()` array and then chooses a random character in that index using the `substring` property and appends it to the `pass` string when the string reaches the defined length it returns the randomly generated password.

this way you can keep your character types separate and also have the ability to add more items to the `AllowedChars()` array with out editing the rest of the function

I know you could do this with just a plain string and get a random `substring` out of it but i prefer to see the differences between UPPER, lowercase, and num3r1c/($pec|@|_) characters.